# I am getting more than one Confirmation Dialog boxes in primeng

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to implement confirm dialog using `primeng` in my angular web application. When I click the button which is supposed to call the method, I get the dialog twice.

I put a console log to check if the method is getting called twice, Turns out, it is getting called once on click. Below is the code.

HTML :

```
<div class="card">
<p>{{eachsecret.title}}</p>
<p>{{eachsecret.date}}</p>
<div class="container">
<i class="pi pi-eye"></i>&nbsp;
<i class="pi pi-download" (click)="download(eachsecret.sid)"></i>&nbsp;
<i class="pi pi-pencil"></i>&nbsp;
<p-confirmDialog [style]="{width: '50vw'}" [baseZIndex]="10000" rejectButtonStyleClass="p-button-text"></p-confirmDialog>
<i class="pi pi-trash" (click)="delete(eachsecret.sid)"></i>&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
```

Delete method :

```
delete(sid) {
      console.log("confirmation dialogue method called");
      this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Are you sure that you want to proceed?',
      header: 'Confirmation',
      icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
      accept: () => {
        this.httpClient.delete(environment.baseURL+'/secret/'+sid, { observe: 'response'}).subscribe(data => {});
        this.messageService.add({severity:'info', summary:'Confirmed', detail:'You have accepted'});},
      reject: () => {this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Rejected', detail:'You have rejected'});}
      });
  }
```

Comment: do you think this might be `event bubbling` - from the `i` tag to the parent `div`?

Answer (score 4):

Assign a key to both confirm method call and html code.

HTML:

```
<p-confirmDialog [style]="{width: '50vw'}" [baseZIndex]="10000" rejectButtonStyleClass="p-button-text" key="myDialog"></p-confirmDialog>
```

TS:

```
this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: 'Are you sure that you want to proceed?',
      header: 'Confirmation',
      icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
      accept: () => {
        this.httpClient.delete(environment.baseURL+'/secret/'+sid, { observe: 'response'}).subscribe(data => {});
        this.messageService.add({severity:'info', summary:'Confirmed', detail:'You have accepted'});},
      reject: () => {this.messageService.add({severity:'error', summary:'Rejected', detail:'You have rejected'});},
      key: "myDialog"
      });
```